# guard-process optipng watch folder for new images

Tags: ruby, optimization, guard

Hi guys can't get my guard-process right, i'm trying to watch a folder for new images and then use optipng to compress them and another command to move them.

```
# Compress png
guard 'process', :name => 'Compress PNG', :command => 'optipng -o7 images/pre/*.png' do
 watch(/^images\/(.*)\.png/)
end

# Move png from pre to images
guard 'process', :name => 'Move png in pre to images root', :command => 'mv images/pre/*.png images/*.png' do
  watch(/^images\/pre\/(.*)\.png/)
end
```

the 1st problem is this doesn't fire when a new image is added to the folder. The next problem is it doesn't seem to like the *.png. Aslo it seems to move the image before optipng has finished.

Answer (score 3):

As I understand, you want to watch new images in /images/pre. When new images arrive, compress them and move them to /images. Your first guard statement should be as follows

```
guard 'process', :name => 'Compress PNG', :command => 'optipng -o7 images/pre/*.png' do
 watch(/^images\/pre\/(.*)\.png/) # Watch images/pre/*.png not images/*.png
end
```

To execute 2 Linux commands in sequence, you can use && or ; (see [here](http://www.skorks.com/2010/05/executing-multiple-commands-a-bash-productivity-tip/))

You can change your command as follows and remove the second guard statement

```
:command => "optipng -o7 images/pre/*.png && mv images/pre/*.png images/*.png"
```